# Is there a windows version of SLAM?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,everybody,I want to know if there is a windows version of SLAM. If there is no ,my next task may be transplanting the code from linux to windows ,which would be a huge work for me ! Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153226/is-there-a-windows-version-of-slam?/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-15

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-15**:
I think that you can choose Mobile Robot Programming Toolkit ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Robot_Programming_Toolkit ) if your task is a research of SLAM. MRPT works on Windows.

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-16**:
MRPT is a cross-platform and open source C++ library ,if I develop a Graphical interface about robot in Visual Studio 2010,I can use MRPT as a libary directly,so there is no need to transplant the code in ROS from linux to windows. Can I understand like that?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-16**:
@danmianjing_00: Exactly!

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-16**:
Thank you. Something else, that is to say,the packages in ROS are generated by buliding a framework with using MRPT libraries,then wrapper packages.So I can use MRPT in VS2010 to wrapper my package to achieve a certain function,such as gmapping package. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@danmianjing_00: I'm not sure. you mean that you will use ROS. There is not a windows version on ROS. If you want to use ROS, I recommend you to learn Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0